# Error occurred while analyze pixel values on two similar images

Tags: java, image, rgb

I am a beginner to Java. Currently I want to analyze two similar images and check whether the images have different pixel values at position 2 and 4. I already develop some codes but when running it, the code produces error and it doesn't looping and check for all pixel values on both images.

For example, in the 9th pixel, image B pixel value at position 2 and 4 are not the same as image A pixel value. Then, whenever the code notices a differences between both images pixel value it will output the statement saying the pixel are not the same.

Here's the code:

```
public class getPixelRGB1
{

private static String[][] img_hex2;
private static String[][] img_hex4;
private static String[][] img2_hex2;
private static String[][] img2_hex4;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream image = null;
    FileInputStream image2 = null;

    getPixelData1 newPD = new getPixelData1();
    compareHexaRGB hexRGB = new compareHexaRGB();


    try {
        BufferedImage img, img2;

        File file = new File("eye1.jpg");
        File file2 = new File("eye2.jpg");
        image = new FileInputStream(file);
        image2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
        img = ImageIO.read(image);
        img2 = ImageIO.read(image2);

        int rowcol;
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();
        hexRGB.compareHexaRGB(width, height);
        System.out.println("Image's Width: " + width);
        System.out.println("Image's Height: " + height);
        //hexRGB.check();
        int[][] pixelData = new int[width * height][3];

        System.out.println("Pixel Data: " + pixelData);

        int[] rgb;
        int count = 0;

        img_hex2 = new String[width][height];
        img_hex4 = new String[width][height];

        for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
            {
                rgb = newPD.getPixelData(img, i, j);

                for(int k = 0; k < rgb.length; k++)
                {
                    pixelData[count][k] = rgb[k];
                    //img_hex2[i][j] = newPD.getHexa2();
                    //img_hex4[i][j] = newPD.getHexa4();
                }
                img_hex2[width][height] = newPD.getHexa2();
                img_hex4[width][height] = newPD.getHexa4();
                System.out.println("Output: " + img_hex2[i][j]);
                System.out.println("Output: " + img_hex4[i][j]);
                count++;
                System.out.println("\nRGB Counts: " + count);
            }
        }

        int width2 = img2.getWidth();
        int height2 = img2.getHeight();
        System.out.println("Image's Width: " + width2);
        System.out.println("Image's Height: " + height2);

        int[][] pixelData2 = new int[width2 * height2][3];

        System.out.println("Pixel Data: " + pixelData2);

        int[] rgb2;
        int counter = 0;

        img_hex2 = new String[width2][height2];
        img_hex4 = new String[width2][height2];

        for(int i=0; i<width2; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<height2; j++)
            {
            rgb2 = newPD.getPixelData(img2, i, j);

            for(int k = 0; k < rgb2.length; k++)
            {
            pixelData2[counter][k] = rgb2[k];

            }
            img2_hex2[width2][height2] = newPD.getHexa2();
            img2_hex4[width2][height2] = newPD.getHexa4();
            counter++;
            System.out.println("\nRGB2 Counts: " + counter);
            }
        }

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getPixelRGB1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        try {
            image.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getPixelRGB1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    hexRGB.check();
}

public String[][] display_imgHex2()
{
    return img_hex2;
}

public String[][] display_imgHex4()
{
    return img_hex4;
}

public String[][] display_img2Hex2()
{
    return img2_hex2;
}

public String[][] display_img2Hex4()
{
    return img2_hex4;
}
}
```

//Get Pixel RGB Process

```
public class getPixelData1 
{
private static final double bitPerColor = 4.0;
private static int red;
private static int green;
private static int blue;
private static String hexa2;
private static String hexa4;

public static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int w, int h) throws IOException
{
    int argb = img.getRGB(w, h);
    int rgb[] = new int[]
    {
        (argb >> 16) & 0xff, //red
        (argb >>  8) & 0xff, //green
        (argb      ) & 0xff  //blue
    };

    red = rgb[0];
    green = rgb[1]; //RGB Value in Decimal
    blue = rgb[2];

    System.out.println("\nRGBValue in Decimal --> " + "\nRed: " + red + " Green: " + green + " Blue: " + blue);

    //Convert each channel RGB to Hexadecimal value
    String rHex = Integer.toHexString((int)(red));
    String gHex = Integer.toHexString((int)(green));
    String bHex = Integer.toHexString((int)(blue));

    System.out.println("\nRGBValue in Hexa --> " + "\nRed Green Blue " + rHex + gHex + bHex);

    return rgb;
}

public String getHexa2()
{
    //Check position 2 of hexa value for any changes

    String hex = String.format("%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue);
    System.out.println("\nString RGB Hexa: " + hex);

    hexa2 = hex.substring(1,2);
    System.out.println("\nSubstring at position 2: " + hexa2);

    return hexa2;
}

public String getHexa4()
{
    //Check position 4 of hexa value for any changes

    String hex = String.format("%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue);
    System.out.println("\nString RGB Hexa: " + hex);

    hexa4 = hex.substring(3,4);
    System.out.println("\nSubstring at position 4: " + hexa4);

    return hexa4;
}

 }
```

//Compare 2 images process

```
public class compareHexaRGB
{
private static int w;
private static int h;

public static void compareHexaRGB(int width, int height) throws IOException
{
    w = width;
    h = height;

}

public void check()
    {
        getPixelRGB1 newPD = new getPixelRGB1();

        for(int i = 0; i < w; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                if(newPD.display_imgHex2().equals(newPD.display_img2Hex2()) && (newPD.display_imgHex4().equals(newPD.display_img2Hex4())))
                {
                    System.out.println("Pixel values at position 2 and 4 are the same.");
                }

                else if(!newPD.display_imgHex2().equals(newPD.display_img2Hex2()) || (!newPD.display_imgHex4().equals(newPD.display_img2Hex4())))
                {
                    System.out.println("Pixel values at position 2 are not the same.");
                }
                else if(!newPD.display_imgHex2().equals(newPD.display_img2Hex2()) || (!newPD.display_imgHex4().equals(newPD.display_img2Hex4())))
                {
                    System.out.println("Pixel values at position 4 are not the same.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at getPixelRGB1.main(getPixelRGB1.java:79)
```

Comment: So it is a NullPointerException! You have a null, by the way, using a debugger is GOOD thing! you can find the root of problem easily!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change you have made is fundamentally incorrect. Please refer this updated class.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class getPixelRGB1 {

    private static String[][] img_hex2;
    private static String[][] img_hex4;
    private static String[][] img2_hex2;
    private static String[][] img2_hex4;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream image = null;
        FileInputStream image2 = null;

        getPixelData1 newPD = new getPixelData1();
        compareHexaRGB hexRGB = new compareHexaRGB();

        try {
            BufferedImage img, img2;

            File file = new File("eye1.jpg");
            File file2 = new File("eye2.jpg");
            image = new FileInputStream(file);
            image2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
            img = ImageIO.read(image);
            img2 = ImageIO.read(image2);

            int rowcol;
            int width = img.getWidth();
            int height = img.getHeight();
            hexRGB.compareHexaRGB(width, height);
            System.out.println("Image's Width: " + width);
            System.out.println("Image's Height: " + height);
            // hexRGB.check();
            int[][] pixelData = new int[width * height][3];

            System.out.println("Pixel Data: " + pixelData);

            int[] rgb;
            int count = 0;

            img_hex2 = new String[width][height];
            img_hex4 = new String[width][height];
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                    rgb = newPD.getPixelData(img, i, j);

                    for (int k = 0; k < rgb.length; k++) {
                        pixelData[count][k] = rgb[k];
                        // img_hex2[i][j] = newPD.getHexa2();
                        // img_hex4[i][j] = newPD.getHexa4();
                    }

                    img_hex2[i][j] = newPD.getHexa2(); // the code runs and
                                                        // stops here
                    img_hex4[i][j] = newPD.getHexa4();
                    System.out.println("Output: " + img_hex2[i][j]);
                    System.out.println("Output: " + img_hex4[i][j]);
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("\nRGB Counts: " + count);
                }
            }

            int width2 = img2.getWidth();
            int height2 = img2.getHeight();
            System.out.println("Image's Width: " + width2);
            System.out.println("Image's Height: " + height2);

            int[][] pixelData2 = new int[width2 * height2][3];

            System.out.println("Pixel Data: " + pixelData2);

            int[] rgb2;
            int counter = 0;

            img2_hex2 = new String[width2][height2];
            img2_hex4 = new String[width2][height2];

            for (int i = 0; i < width2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < height2; j++) {
                    rgb2 = newPD.getPixelData(img2, i, j);

                    for (int k = 0; k < rgb2.length; k++) {
                        pixelData2[counter][k] = rgb2[k];

                    }
                    img2_hex2[i][j] = newPD.getHexa2();
                    img2_hex4[i][j] = newPD.getHexa4();
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println("\nRGB2 Counts: " + counter);
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getPixelRGB1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                image.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getPixelRGB1.class.getName()).log(
                        Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        hexRGB.check();
    }

    public String[][] display_imgHex2() {
        return img_hex2;
    }

    public String[][] display_imgHex4() {
        return img_hex4;
    }

    public String[][] display_img2Hex2() {
        return img2_hex2;
    }

    public String[][] display_img2Hex4() {
        return img2_hex4;
    }
}
```

Comment: now it runs ok with looping. but the output shows the same output for all pixel values saying that the pixel value at position 2 are not the same. fyi, only some of the pixel has different values on both images. i guess my code maybe wrong somewhere in compareHexRGB method. could you help?

Comment: In the check() method, the comparison is incorrect. 
if(newPD.display_imgHex2().equals(newPD.display_img2Hex2()) && (newPD.display_imgHex4().equals(newPD.display_img2Hex4())))

The two objects display_imgHex2() and display_img2Hex2() are compared. Instead their individual elementsshould be compared as follows.

if(newPD.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(newPD.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]) && (newPD.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(newPD.display_img2Hex4()[i][j])))

The same modification should be done for elseif statements as well.

Comment: thank you! now the output is correct. i can proceed to my next process which is the extraction process. i'm still in the middle in developing the code. and hopefully it turns out okay.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the four uninitialized variables at the top.

```
private static String[][] img_hex2;
private static String[][] img_hex4;
private static String[][] img2_hex2;
private static String[][] img2_hex4;
```

The above four variables are accessed without allocating any memory.

A quick fix is to initialize them before the two for loops that use them.

```
    img_hex2 = new String[width][height];
    img_hex4 = new String[width][height];
    for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
        {
        .....

    img2_hex2 = new String[width2][height2];
    img2_hex4 = new String[width2][height2];;


    for(int i=0; i<width2; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<height2; j++
```

Comment: I've changed to what you suggested. the error comes out Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at getPixelRGB1.main(getPixelRGB1.java:79). what should i do now?

Comment: Do you mind sharing more specific information. For instance, the code line @ getPixelRGB1.java:79.

Comment: i did this: 
img_hex2 = newPD.getHexa2();
img_hex4 = newPD.getHexa4(); // error stated that string cannot be converted to string[][]

but if i did this:
img_hex2[width][height] = newPD.getHexa2();
img_hex4[width][height] = newPD.getHexa4(); // error arrayindexoutofbounds occur